# Patterns in nested for loops

Tags: python-3.x

In python I need the output to be the following, I included the image of the output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8xYp.png)

```
1
2 4
3 6 9
4 8 12 16 
5 10 15 20 25
6 12 18 24 30 36
7 14 21 28 35 42 49
8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64
9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

I've tried googling the answer but I don't get the exact pattern

Comment: You need to look into [operators](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp), [for loops](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) and that should be enough to figure it out. When you make a post make sure you provide an example of what you have tried so far, asking for somebody to give you code is a great way to be given code that you won't understand. A good place to start would have been just printing out the first number of each row.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you want pattern matching. You can achieve this result with a simple for loop.

```
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print((i*j), end=" ")
    print("\n")
```

Comment: I'm a beginner in programming so this is for school work.Thank you it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

this should give you the result you want.

```
_______ = 9
for __, ____ in enumerate(list(range(1,_______+1))):
  _____ = f"{____}"
  for ___ in range(1,__+1):
    _____ = f"{_____} {____*(___+1)}"
  print(_____)
```